# Odoo 8.0 product_product inherit extend class

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm getting my first step into odoo.
I'm trying to extend product model class like this.

```
from openerp.osv import osv,fields as fields

class product_product(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.product'
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    _columns = {
        'products_ids':fields.one2many('product_application.version', 'version_id', string="Versions")
    }
```

and getting the following error

```
  File "/home/nano/ARCHIVOS/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 596, in _build_model
    original_module = pool[name]._original_module if name in parents else cls._module
  File "/home/nano/ARCHIVOS/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 102, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'product.product'
```

Can anyone point me a complete odoo v8 documentation, the official is poor

Comment: If you are inheriting the `product.product` class you are modifying the product variants. Maybe what you want is to modify the `product.template` class, don't you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting 'Keyerror'

so please check whether you gave correct depends in **openerp**.py
ie, you have to give 'product' in depends

Give like this:-
'depends': ['base', 'product'],

Hope this helps...

Comment: yes it help! 
Solved adding 'product' to dependes in __openerp__.py

Answer (score 2):

In odoo the _name creates a new table in the backend database.
 So, here the problem is you are using while inheriting _name = 'product.product' which is already existing in the DB (base class product).
 Also if you want normal inheritance no need of _name attribute, simply you can extend by _inherit only. 
The kind of inheritance which you are using, in that the _name should not be equal to _inherit (_name != _inherit). So, either give a new name to _name='new.name'
for more clarification check this link 
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: Alredy try that, in the link says to use _name  = _inheret.
Solved adding 'product' to dependes in __openerp__.py

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields,osv
class product_product(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.product'
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    _columns = {
         'products_ids':fields.one2many('product_application.version', 'version_id', string="Versions")
    }
```

I don't know why you're using "fields as fields"?

Or else check that have you installed "Product" module?

Comment: Solved adding 'product' to dependes in __openerp__.py.
Thanks!